# Will the untimely cherry blossom in Japan impacts the regular cycle in spring?

Tags: japan

I am planning to visit Japan in the spring season to see the Cherry Blossom. However, due to recent reports of early bloom, I am a little skeptical of our visit. Will the regular cycle be impacted due to the recent bloom?

Comment: What's with the downvotes? This is a perfectly legitimate question.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**No**, the impact is expected to be minimal.

> The buds that are flourishing now in Japan won’t open again in the spring, but fortunately, the proportion of blossoms that have opened in recent days is relatively small. So, Wada tells NHK, the unseasonal bloom is not likely to affect the splendor of the cherry blossoms next spring.

Source: https://www.smithsonianmag.com/smart-news/why-are-japans-cherry-blossom-trees-blooming-fall-180970590/